# Can we use Html.Raw() to display special characters

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is html.Raw() ? 
Can it be used to display special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Text output will generally be HTML encoded.  Using `Html.Raw` allows you to output text containing html elements to the client, and have them still be rendered as such.  Should be used with caution, as it exposes you to cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

```
Wraps HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted as HTML markup.
```

MSDN [Link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)